# Looking for Windows Text Editor which supports GIT

Tags: python, git, ide, editor

I am looking for a Text Editor on Windows which is integrated with GIT (check out, check in from the UI). Also, it would be nice is this editor could also support Python syntax highlighting.

Is there anything like that available?

Thanks!

Comment: This should not be marked a duplicate.  The linked article is asking 'how can I select a different text editor when writing commit messages'.  This question is how can I find a windows Text Editor (or IDE) that has a plugin and/or native support for Git (clone, push, fetch).  @nawfal

Answer (score 4):

Here's a [list of Editors and IDEs that integrate GIT](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools#EditorsandIDEintegration), not sure if there's something that fits your need. The most fitting would be the [Eclipse Plugin](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/EclipsePlugin).

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse should be able to fit the bill.  I know there's a decent python plugin, and I'm sure there's one for git by now.

Answer (score 1):

[E Text Editor](http://e-texteditor.com/) is the  text editor for windows that i fell in love with. It "has support" for GIT via the project pane, because the project pane works with [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/). Depending on your preferences this may or may not be the optimal setup.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried vim with this plugin?

http://github.com/motemen/git-vim